# Iris - How to log erros/exceptions?

Tags: go

I'm testing a Go application using [Iris](https://github.com/kataras/iris).
I want to log every error or exception to my Rollbar account.

For instance, if the endpoint takes too long to respond and there is a timeout, I want to log it. How can I capture errors like that?

**Update**

I found in the documentation the `OnError` method, and I thought I could use it like this:

```
iris.OnError(iris.StatusServiceUnavailable, func(c *iris.Context) {
    c.Write("503")
    params := string(c.RequestCtx.Request.Body())
    rollbar.Error("error", errors.New("503 Service Unavailable"), &rollbar.Field{Name: "request_body", Data: params})
})
```

But it is not logging the error to Rollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to write your own [iris middleware](https://kataras.gitbooks.io/iris/content/middleware.html).

Should look something like this:

```
func irisMiddlewareFunc(ctx *iris.Context) {
    startedAt := time.Now()
    ctx.Next()
    timeTaken := time.Since(startedAt)

    // now check time taken and log as required
    if timeTaken.Seconds() > 2 {
        fmt.Println("Taken too long")
    }
}
```

The you use it like this:

```
    iris.UseFunc(irisMiddlewareFunc)
```

And if you need to handle panics as well, just use recover() as you would usually do to handle panics. See [github.com/iris-contrib/middleware/recovery](http://github.com/iris-contrib/middleware/recovery)
 for an example.

Comment: That looks interesting. But shouldn't be `Next()` the last call in this function?

Comment: No. in simple words, Next() calls next handler in the chain of processing (last of which will be the handler of the request). They called chaining, but I'd rather suggest thinking about them rather like a Russian doll than a chain. If you move Next() call to the end of firmware, then all your measuring and logging will happen before you handler is called.

Comment: Another example would be github.com/iris-contrib/middleware/logger. Look at Serve() method.

Comment: Understood, thanks! I updated my question, do you know why that solution didn't work?

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't use OnError() in my code. First of all, OnError() is only called  when your own handler sets that response status (such as 503). And 503 is most likely generated by a load balancer or proxy without actually accessing your service. If you set 503 status in your own code, check that iris.onError() is called before iris.Get(). I'm not sure if  this is important, but would suspect it is. See https://kataras.gitbooks.io/iris/content/custom-http-errors.html. Note how iris.onError() calls precede iris.Get() calls there.

Comment: You can also check http status of the response in the above middleware handler by calling ctx.Response.StatusCode() after ctx.Next(). Again, github.com/iris-cont‌​rib/middleware/logger‌​ is another example of doing that.